# Run a local http from browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, cmd

I have to open a web page (which is on a local server) from Run/Powershell/whatever.

In the Run Window, I write that :

```
firefox \\192.168.167.147\test.php
```

or on Powershell :

```
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("firefox", "\\192.168.167.147\test.php")
```

Firefox starts but open this page :

```
file://///192.168.167.24/test.php
```

instead of

```
192.168.167.24/test.php
```

Same on Chrome.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason not to open firefox http:// 192.168.167.147/test.php  OR http:// localhost/test.php ?

Comment: Thanks !!! it is the solution !

Comment: glad to help. Using \\ in windows will use file:// protocol by default. Same if you type \\192.168.167.147 directly in firefox or chrome (or Windows Explorer by the way)

Comment: Thanks ! please send this as an answer, thus I can accept it

Comment: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer>iexplore www.google.co.in this can open google in internet explorer. You can build on this for other browsers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\\` will use the `file://` protocol by default.

The same happens if you type `\\192.168.167.147` directly in Firefox's or Chrome's address bar (or Windows Explorer by the way)

You need to explicitly use the protocol you want to use `http://` or `ftp://` or whatever

**firefox http://192.168.167.147/test.php** will do it

Answer (score 2):

**In the Run Window,**

> For Chrome

```
chrome http://192.168.167.24/test.php
```

> For Firefox

```
firefox http://192.168.167.24/test.php
```

Comment: Why would you need to set localhosts for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question very much ,

But I usually use vhosts/.conf file in wampserver to create local hosts

ex: test.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "d:/example/repos/public"
    ServerName local.example.domain.com
    ServerAlias local.example.domain.com        
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "d:/example/repos/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Hope this helps